# How to check if all array items are consecutive and finish at value 9

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have an array of user defined length `0<n<10` and I want to check if `arr[i]-arr[i-1] == 1` for all pairs i know I can iterate over them but I was wondering if there is an easier way that I could put inside of the `if` .

Edit: I just realised while tinkering with this that I don't know how to do it even iterating I need last item to be 9!

what I have:

```
bool is_consecutive(int arr[], int leng)
{
    int i = 0;
    if (leng > 1)
    {
        while (i < n)
        {
            if (arr[i+1]-arr[i] != 1)
                return false;
            else if ( i == leng - 1 && arr[i] == 9)
                return true
        }
    }
    else if (arr[leng-1] == 9)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's anything simpler than iterating.

Comment: @Barmar I just realised I don't know how to do it even iterating

Comment: Please show what you have attempted and what problem you have with that.

Comment: What you wrote in the question should work.

Comment: Show how you tried to use that in the loop, and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: @Barmar I updated it, I forgot to metion that the last num has to be 9 always

Comment: You didn't forget to mention that, it's in the question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems:

1. The index of the last element is `leng-1`, not `leng`.
2. Your loop is accessing outside the array when it gets to the last iteration. You should limit the iteration to `i < leng-1` so that `i+1` is inside the array.

It's simpler to check the last element before the loop.

And instead of special-casing the last index, if you make it to the end of the loop without returning `false`, you know it was successful so you can return `true` after the loop.

```
bool is_consecutive(int arr[], int leng)
{
    if (arr[leng-1] != 9) {
        return false;
    }
    if (leng == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    int i = 0;
    while (i < leng - 1) {
        if (arr[i+1]-arr[i] != 1) {
            return false;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It's for an exercise I cant use for loops

Comment: OK, I've converted the for loop to the equivalent while loop.

Comment: You really don't need to check for the special case where `leng == 1`. That case is perfectly handled by your loop. The case where `leng==0` on the other hand...

Answer (score -1):

Well, you don't really need to compare two different elements of the array

```c
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_consecutive(int n, int arr[], int last_value)
{
    if ( n <= 0 )
        return false;
    while ( --n ) {
        if ( arr[n] != last_value-- )
        //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   You know how it should end and that all
        //                            the elements should be consecutive.
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Testable [here](https://godbolt.org/z/EbT1x1Pja).

Comment: the function doesn't really need `int last_value` does it? I can just use n as lenght and compare it to 9.

Edit: I see why its there

Comment: @MiguelM Yes, I added it just to be more generic.